# Find total number of possible combination of letters in a given word in C language

Tags: arrays, c, combinations, permutation

I have a question that I am not able to solve.

Alex wants to test his child's ability of identifying correct spelling of a word from a group of jumbled words. To jumble the words they want to find out how many ways a word can be rearranged. For example if they want to rearrange a word "whats" where the letters are unique, the number of ways can be found by finding 5!. It the word is "hello" where letter 'l' alone is repeated twice, the number of ways a word can be rearranged can be found out by 5!/2!(no of letters!/number of repeated letter count!). If the word is "little" where two letters 'l' and 't' are repeated twice, then number of ways to arrange letters is 6!/(2!*2!). Write a recursive function to find factorial.

Input: String to rearrange.
Output: Integer denoting the number of ways a letter can be jumbled.

Sample Test:
Input: document
Output: 40320

I tried this code(C language):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int seq(char arr[], int len) {
    int i, j, cnt[100], rf, nf, r;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        int ct=0;
        for (j=i;i<len;j++) {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                ct++; 
        }
        cnt[i]=ct;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=len;i++)
        nf *= i;
    size_t size = sizeof(cnt)/sizeof(cnt[0]);
    for (j=0;j<size;j++) {
        for (i=1;i<cnt[j];i++)
           rf *= i;
        r *= rf;
    }
    return nf/r;
}

int main() {
    char arr[100];
    scanf("%s", arr);
    printf("%d", seq(arr, strlen(arr)));
}
```

Expected:
Input: Whats
Output: 120

Actual:
Input: Whats
Output:
****Run Error****
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Start with turning on compiler warnings (also turn on optimisations). Fix all problems that arise. Not all compilers will find every problem here. Use a debugger to find what remains.

Answer (score 2):

There are several bugs.  One is that almost all of the variables used to calculate factorials are uninitialized.  Those need to be initialized to 1.

There are also some typos.  For example, `for (j=i;i<len;j++)` should be `for (j=i;j<len;j++)` (the `i` in the comparison needs to be `j`).

And the loop `for (i=1;i<cnt[j];i++)`, which calculates the factorials of the duplicated letters, needs to include the final count, i.e. it needs to be `for (i=1;i<=cnt[j];i++)`.

Also, this part:

```
size_t size = sizeof(cnt)/sizeof(cnt[0]);
for (j=0;j<size;j++) {
```

always forces the loop to run from `0` to `99`.  It should run from `0` to `len-1`, i.e. those two lines need to be replaced with:

```
for (j=0;j<len;j++) {
```

Here's a version that fixes these problems:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int seq(char arr[], int len) {
    int i, j, cnt[100], rf, nf, r;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        int ct=0;
        for (j=i;j<len;j++) {
            if (arr[i]==arr[j])
                ct++;
        }
        cnt[i]=ct;
    }
    nf = 1;
    for (i=1;i<=len;i++)
        nf *= i;
    r = 1;
    for (j=0;j<len;j++) {
        rf = 1;
        for (i=1;i<=cnt[j];i++)
           rf *= i;
        r *= rf;
    }
    return nf/r;
}

int main() {
    char arr[100];
    scanf("%s", arr);
    printf("%d\n", seq(arr, strlen(arr)));
}
```

I also added a newline to the end of the `printf` format string.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problems:

**Code compiled without all compiler warnings enable**

At least 3 issues warned about.

**Uninitialized variables**

`nf *= i;`, `r *= rf;` used without `nf, r, rf` being assigned.

**Loop count wrong**

`for (j=0;j<size;j++) {` iterates `size` times even though `cnt[j]` only assigned `len` times.

**Wrong test**

Review `for (j = i; i < len; j++) {` stopping condition.

**`int` overflow**

Code like `nf *= i` readily overflows.  Use a wider type for `nf` and check for overflow potential.

**Buffer overflow**

Input risks overflow without a *width*.

```
// scanf("%s", arr);
scanf("%99s", arr);
```